# Please help Identify this plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, leaves

Its growing nicely in a pot, but we have no idea what it is.

We’re in the Caribbean, if that helps.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it's in the Ginger family, like turmeric, ginger,  or bananas.

Comment: @Shule or maybe dieffenbachia or aglaonema?

Comment: It looks like a small banana plant also.  Hard to tell.